# I would like to customize ElasticOutCurve, but how should I go about it?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, math

I'm using [ElasticOutCurve](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ElasticOutCurve-class.html) to add animation, but I want to increase the height of the bounce, but I don't know how.
If I modify the part marked by the red circle in the graph in the attached image downwards on the X-axis, it will become the bound I imagine, but I don't know how to implement it in the Dart language.
How can I change the calculation formula to correct the red circle part toward the bottom?

[image]

```dart
class CustomElasticOutCurve extends Curve {
  const CustomElasticOutCurve({this.period = 0.4});
  final double period;

  @override
  double transformInternal(double t) {
    final s = period / 4.0;
    return math.pow(2.0, -10 * t) *
            math.sin((t - s) * (math.pi * 2.0) / period) +
        1.0;
  }
}
```